# Passing AWS region and account ID to swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am defining my API Gateway APIs using AWS SAM

```
ApiGatewayApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    DefinitionUri: swagger.yml
    StageName: prod
    Variables:
      Region: !Ref AWS::Region
      AccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      Ec2Index: !Ref Ec2Index
      AuthLogin: !Ref AuthLogin
      Ec2Patch: !Ref Ec2Patch
      AutoScalingIndex: !Ref AutoScalingIndex
      AutoScalingPatch: !Ref AutoScalingPatch
      AutoScalingScale: !Ref AutoScalingScale
```

In my swagger file:

paths:
  /auth/session:
    post:
      produces:
      - application/json
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:598545985414:function:${stageVariables.AuthLogin}/invocations
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
      responses:
        200:
          description: App token
        401:
          description: 401
        403:
          description: 403

AWS CloudFormation errors saying

> Errors found during import: Unable to put integration on 'POST' for resource at path '/auth/session': Lambda function ARN must be in same account Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/autoscaling': Lambda function ARN must be in same account Unable to put integration on 'PATCH' for resource at path '/autoscaling/{groupName}': Lambda function ARN must be in same account Unable to put integration on 'POST' for resource at path '/autoscaling/{groupName}/scale': Lambda function ARN must be in same account Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/ec2': Lambda function ARN must be in same account Unable to put integration on 'PATCH' for resource at path '/ec2/{id}': Lambda function ARN must be in same account

Seems like my ARN is invalid. This is resolved once I remove the variables. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

As of now swagger does not allow AccountId in stage variables. It's a limitation of the API Gateway.

You can get around this by just using a stage variable for the function name only and piece the rest together like this:

```
//does not get passed in. This is just a placeholder for the stage variable
Parameters: 
    ApiFunctionName:
        Type: String
        Description: Function name of the api lambda function
        Default: ${stageVariables.yourFunctionNameVar}

//in your gateway path   
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: 
          !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${ApiFunctionName}/invocations"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Passing variables](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/8) to swagger is not possible to do at this moment from a SAM template, but you can copy entire swagger file in the template file as `DefinitionBody` and reference variables the same way *provided swagger definition is not huge*.

> SAM template is currently limited to 51.2 KB